# Find all degenerate eigenvalues of a cubic equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, linear-algebra, physics

I have an equation that is cubic in `w`. The three solutions correspond to bands in a bandstructure, and are a function of wavevector `{x, y}`. Additionally it is parameterised by `0 <= θ <= π` and `0 <= φ <= 2 π`. I need a procedure that takes `θ` and `φ` as inputs, and can reliably calculate if there are any points at all in wavevector space where either two or all of the bands touch (i.e. are there any values of `{x, y}` which give rise to a degenerate solution `w`). Ideally the procedure would then be able to calculate the coordinates in momentum space of these touching points. The code to generate the cubic equation is given below.

```
M = {{s, ab, ac}, {ab, s, bc}, {ac, bc, s}};
w = ToRadicals[Eigenvalues[M]];
f[e_] := 2 Norm[e]^-3 (1 - 3 Sin[θ]^2 Cos[φ - ArcTan[e[[1]], e[[2]]]]^2)Cos[{x, y}.e];
ab = f[{1, 0}];
ac = f[{0, 1}];
bc = f[{1, 1}] + f[{-1, 1}];
s = f[{2, 0}] + f[{0, 2}];
```

A slight variation on this question has already been solved [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87456) by @bbgodfrey and others and can serve as a more detailed reference. However that question called for a solution when *all three* bands touch, as opposed to two or more, which is the current question.

One of my ultimate goals is to be able to generate a plot in `{θ, φ}` space showing what values give rise to a bandstructure with touching points. As an example, in previous work a procedure for a different physical system generated the plot below, where purple is a gapless bandstructure and cream is a gapped bandstructure:

[image: band structure plot]

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks for suggesting I create a new question. Here it is.

Comment: Any reason not to use `Eigenvalues[]` here?

Comment: It always spits out something in the form of Root[] which I didn't really know how to handle, so I did it this way.

Comment: That's its default behavior; if you want radicals in your output, use `ToRadicals[]`.

Comment: Thanks. Have modified question to incorporate this.

Comment: BTW, have you tried using `Discriminant[]` on the `CharacteristicPolynomial[]` of `M`? `Reduce[]` should be useful in determining conditions for that expression to be zero.

Comment: Yes in the linked previous question I explain three attempted solutions to that similar question. I'm aware that if the discriminant of a cubic equation is equal to zero then all three roots are real and at least two are degenerate, so this is an ideal condition to use. However I couldn't then solve the resulting equation discriminant=0 and find the {x,y} solutions for a given {theta,phi}. From previous studies I know some touching points that exist such as {Pi,Pi} for example, and then I am able to solve discriminant=0 for a particular known {x,y} and find all {theta,phi} that satisfy...

Comment: but I don't seem to be able to do the reverse.

Comment: ps I have edited the question because one of us has introduced a typo into the code from editing. The arctan needs to be inside the cos squared. have modified.

Comment: It won't happen at isolated points. Your one constraint is that, as a function of the angular parameters, the discriminant of that matrix characteristic polynomial vanishes. One equation, two variable (`x` and `y`). (Upshot: where all three vanish is actually more than a "slight variation").

Comment: I know for certain that there are specific combinations of `{\[Theta],\[Phi]}`  for which there *are* points `{x,y}` where all three solutions are equal, the bands touch. This is demonstrated in the previous question. You can use more than just the discriminant equal to zero constraint. You could also search for values of `x` and `y` where two solutions are equal. I think maybe I've not fully understood your comment though.

Comment: @Tom if you don't mention the user your comment is directed to as `@johndoe` he won't be notified and you'll never get an answer to it

Comment: @belisarius thanks, although who is @johndoe? I don't see his username anywhere else on this question

Comment: My comment is that the solution space for having two coinciding roots is not a discrete set, it is one dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

For a numerical approximation you  may try something like:

```
M = {{s, ab, ac}, {ab, s, bc}, {ac, bc, s}};
disc = Discriminant[CharacteristicPolynomial[M, x], x] // FullSimplify
f[e_] := 2 Norm[e]^-3 (1 - 3 Sin[θ]^2 Cos[φ - ArcTan[e[[1]], e[[2]]]]^2) Cos[{x, y}.e];
ab = f[{1, 0}];
ac = f[{0, 1}];
bc = f[{1, 1}] + f[{-1, 1}];
s = f[{2, 0}] + f[{0, 2}];

Quiet@RegionPlot[With[{θ = t, φ = p},
                FindMinValue[disc, {x, y}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]] < 10^-6,
                {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 60]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should take care of the numeric subtleties. Please note:

```
Quiet@RegionPlot[
                FindMinValue[disc /. {θ -> t, φ -> p}, {{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}}] < .001, 
                {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oooo interesting thank you very much. I'll have a play with this.